# Convert 3D view to 2D view in Forge Autodesk Viewer

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I want to convert 3D view to 2D view. [reference link](https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/how-get-2d-line-style-view-3d-models). but this is working fine till Autodesk Forge Viewer v6.
[Autodesk Forge Viewer v6 - image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nlcMx.png)
but now NPR moved in Autodesk.NPR extension. After using this extension I am getting output like this
[Autodesk Forge Viewer v7 - image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/micDp.png) 
 I am using Autodesk Forge Viewer v7 (Angular Forge Viewer component). How can I remove this noise in lines for 2D view?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the recently added noise in the Non-Photo Realistic rendering is not configurable at the moment. The ability to configure the noise is currently a work in progress. Before it's available, please revert to older version of the viewer if you need the NPR effect without the noise.